# Versions of .net framework in Windows

Tags: windows, .net, framework

I am performing a small feasibly test before building my app. Currently I have several options. The first includes building an application that combines silverlight and activex. Now activex can work with only .net framework 1.1 installed on the client's computer.

The other possibility is working with XAPBs which demand .net framework 3.0.

So my question is, What are the framework versions that automatically come with windows XP (including patches and service packs). It's very important for understanding if what I am trying to develop has any market at all...

Thank you!

Comment: If you want the biggest market code for Java and/or Flash - that way you get the linux and mac users too.

Comment: I am a c# developer, don't program in those languages...

Comment: Since you're going to have to specify a version I'd pick framework 3.5

Comment: Silverlight is available for Mac natively and linux via Moonlight.  ActiveX, not so much.

Answer (score 5):

XP didn't ship with any .NET, SP1 and 2 had v1.0 as an option, SP3 installed v1.0+bugfixes by default. Server 2003 shipped with v1.1, Vista and Server 2008 with v3.0 and finally W7 and 2008R2 with v3.5. All can run 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 & 4.0b1 if installed/updated.

Comment: I don't think you can actually install the any 1.x framework versions on Vista and beyond.  However, assemblies compiled for 1.x can theoretically run without issue under 2.x and beyond.

Comment: I put 1.1 on server 2008 just last week

Comment: You can scertainly put 1.1 on an version up to and past XP/2003

Comment: ok I see. Thank you chopper. Do you have any kind of estimation of what is the percentage of windows OSes that have .net framework 2 \ 3 installed on them? Where can I check out this kind of information?

Comment: 2.0 only really shipped with Visual Studio 2005 but I'd imagine 50% have 1.1, 20% with 3.0 and <10 with 3.5 - total guess though

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand the implications of your question with regards to activex,  but my understanding is that silverlight is something that runs in the browser (yes I know that the newest version can run out of the browser) within a sandboxed security environment, and the Silverlight runtime is a standalone installation with a reduced set of .Net base class libraries.

If my understanding is correct, then wouldn't the version of .Net installed on the OS be irrelevant (providing that a given browser has Silverlight support).

Comment: +1 Yes, this is true.  Silverlight has its own self-contained version of the .NET CLR with irrelevant assemblies excluded (such as ASP.NET, WinForms, etc).